# Horizontal RecyclerView inside vertical ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

So I have a horizontal RecyclerView inside a vertical ScrollView. Everything inside my layout is displayed fine and it all scrolls in the directions I want and it does it smoothly.

The only problem I have, is that the RecyclerView is below some other content in the ScrollView and when the RecyclerView is partially visible, it will line the bottom of the RecyclerView with the bottom of the screen on start-up. This means that the content above the RecyclerView is pushed off the screen.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it?

Here is a simple layout that does what I just described. You don't even need to populate the RecyclerView, it will still do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="#fff"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/.

Comment: From what I know of TwoWayView, it's not really relevant to my question, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out this issue was reported to Google here [Issue - 81854](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81854&q=recyclerview%20scrollview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

According to Google it is working as intended. The problem is the fact that RecyclerView has `focusableInTouchMode` set to true. To fix the problem I set `focusableInTouchMode` and `focusable` to true on the top-most view of the ScrollView.

Below is the fix for the code sample I provided in the original question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You said to set `focusableInTouchMode` and `focusable` to true on the top-most view of the ScrollView. But in code I see something different. Please clarify.

Comment: @Parsi Sorry. Since ScrollView can only have one child, I meant the top-most view of the ScrollView child.

Comment: I din't get that then. Thank you. No mention :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a solution for a long time. In the end, I decided by accident. In your activity, find the ScrollView and add a touch listener for it. Everything will work as it should

```
ScrollView scroll = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        scroll.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
            return false;
        });
```